# .map with typescript, where to insert the interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

Trying a couple of things out with React, NextJS and Typescript.  I  am running into a problem where I keep getting the "x does not exist on type 'boolean | any[]'. Property 'x' does not exist on type 'false'.ts(2339)" error.  I just don't know where to put the interface to show it what types this is using.  Can anyone help me out?  Here is the offending code!

Articles.js

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react'; // we need this to make JSX compile
import useFetch from '../hooks/fetch'
type artProps = {
    title: string,
    author: string,
    date: number
}
type article = {
    title: string,
    author: string,
    date: number
}

export const Articles: FunctionComponent<{artProps}> = () => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:4000/kb'

    const data = useFetch(url)
    console.log(data)
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map(articles) => {
                return (<div key={article.id}>
                    {console.log(article)}
                    <h2 key={article.id}>{article.title} </h2>
                    <p key={article.id}>{article.body}</p>
                </div>
                )
            })}
            {/* {artProps.map(artProp => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h2>{artProp.title}</h2>
                        <p>{artProp.author}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            })
            } */}
        </div>
    )
}
export default Articles
```

The hook

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('fetch')
        axios.get(url)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data) {
                    setData(res.data)
                    setLoading(false)
                }
            })
    }
        , []);


    return [data, loading];
};

export default useFetch
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const useFetch = <T>(url: string): [T, boolean] => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('fetch')
        axios.get(url)
            .then((res: any) => {
                if (res.data) {
                    setData(res.data)
                    setLoading(false)
                }
            })
    }
        , []);


    return [data, loading];
};

export default useFetch
```

Now add this to the parent component...

```
useFetch<ArrayTypeHere>(url)
```

now .map will infer the correct type and no need for annotations or type casting.

Comment: This gave me a ton of errors.  I'm using CRA, and aI couldn't get this to load in tsx without a lot of errors.  Can't use .ts